# django: Setting environment variables in /etc/apache2/envvar is not working

Tags: python, django, apache

I have a Django `(v1.11.6)` app on my Ubuntu server having `Python 3.5 (not using virtualenv)`.

However, I want to set environment variables in mod_wsgi for Django.

Since I'm not using `virtualenv` I set then in `/etc/apache2/envvar`. But `apache2` service can't get them.

In settings.py I have `SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable("GA_SECRET_KEY")` but apache raises the following error:

```
[Mon Oct 23 14:03:29.180611 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 30062] [client 194.42.16.145:13576]     SECRET_KEY = os.environ("GA_SECRET_KEY")
[Mon Oct 23 14:03:29.180630 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 30062] [client 194.42.16.145:13576] TypeError: '_Environ' object is not callable
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to set the environent variables in `apache2.conf` file like:

```
SetEnv SECRET_KEY '123456778877'
```

And then in `wsgi.py` file have the following code:

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

_application = get_wsgi_application()

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    # pass the WSGI environment variables on through to os.environ
    os.environ['SECRET_KEY'] = environ['GA_SECRET_KEY']
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

And then in `settings.py` file have:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ[SECRET_KEY]
```